# Make webpack fail on undefined named imports

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, material-ui

Webpack 4.29 will build bundles that contain named ES2015 imports that are not present, resulting in runtime errors. Is there a way of making it detect this at build time and throw an error (message)?

**Real life example**
When upgrading Material UI from 1.0-beta to 3.x a lot of modules and exports have been moved around. This results in code like this producing errors, as the named exports have been moved into files of their own:

```
import Card, {CardHeader} from '@material-ui/core/Card';
```

I then need to change this into

```
import Card       from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
```

to avoid a runtime error. Currently, only strong test coverage is somewhat saving my ass from discovering this at runtime.